# How to use withoutActuallyEscaping with filter and compact map swift

Tags: swift, closures

I have this filter and map

```
let listItems = openingHours.lazy.filter {
                $0.openingHourOpen.day.lowercased() == day.lowercased()
                }
                .compactMap { createListItem(thisDay: $0, day: day, isFirstDay: &firstDay) }
```

Because I'm using lazy it requires that I use self.createList which I don't think is necessary.
When I create a capture list for unowned I get 'unowned' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'Information'

So my idea is to wrap it in a withoutActuallyEscaping but I'm unsure on the syntax.

```
let listItems: [ListItem]  = withoutActuallyEscaping((OpeningHour) -> ListItem) { type  in
                 openingHours.lazy.filter {  $0.openingHourOpen.day.lowercased() == day.lowercased() }
                 .compactMap{ createListItem(thisDay: $0, day: day, isFirstDay: &firstDay)}
            }
```

but I get an error of Definition conflicts with previous value and
Expression type '(*, (*) throws -> _) throws -> _' is ambiguous without more context